# LC-3 Assembly Language - swapping values

Tags: linux, assembly, lc3

How can I swap to values in an address. Currently I have 2 registers which contain the addresses. I then had 2 temporary variables which stores those addresses. I then loaded the values since I have the address. But I can not figure out how to swap the values. I am trying to do bubble sort. The code below is what I currently have

```
IF          ;swapping condition
   ST R2,idata    ;temporily hold the smaller data
   ST R1,imindata ;temporaily hold the larger data
   ST R2,iminaddres ;store the values into that address
   ST R2,iaddress   ;finish the swaping of the two values
   LD R1,iminaddres ;reput the address back into the register
   LD R2,iaddres    ;reput the address back into the register to be used for next cycle
```

Comment: What's not working?  How do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

How would you do it in C?

```
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

Then understand there is a need to load those values from memory, which changes things a bit

```
tempa = a;
tempb = b;
b = tempa;
a = tempb;
```

then isolate the loads and stores

```
rega <= load(a);
regb <= load(b);
store(a) <= regb;
store(b) <= rega;
```

then implement that in assembly.  This smells like a homework assignment so I wont do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is swap the contents of two registers, there's a simple bit-twiddling trick:

```
XOR R1,R2
XOR R2,R1
XOR R1,R2
```

This will exchange the contents of the two registers without using any memory.

Comment: I actually want to change the contents at the memory address not the register. How would you approach that?

Comment: lc3 doesnt have an xor, it can be done with the not and and, but takes a bunch of instructions.